# search all videos with CC transcription in specific language

Tags: youtube-api, closed-captions

I'm trying to achieve two things:
1) find all videos with transcriptions in a certain language, or
2) Find all videos with transcription in Lang A and translated subtitles in lang B, preferably with the ability to distinguish human translation from automated translation.

I saw in another post that you can query all videos with captions with the code below. Is there a way to modify this to specify which languages and distinguish the transcription from translation? Thanks

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'videoCaption' => 'closedCaption',
  'type' => 'video'
));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if all this feature is available in Youtube Data API. AFAIK, you can list all cc of a video but if you want to get only a specific language you have to create your own code or use [Captions: download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) and specify the language of the caption to be downloaded.

Comment: For your other concern, to check if the cc is an automated translation or human, the closest would be using the parameter trackKind. This parameter tells if the caption is an automatic speech recognition, forced – A caption track that plays when no other track is selected in the player or standard – A regular caption track. There is document telling if the caption is translated automatically or using human translation.